# How can I save a listbox in a text file

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have 2 Forms, on `Form1` I have a button and in the `Form2` I have a `ListBox` with data.
What I want is to click the button on `Form1` and save the data from the `Form2` `ListBox` in a text file.

What I have tried:

This is button on Form1

```
private void toolStripButtonGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myForm = new FormVer();

        //Escolher onde salvar o arquivo
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        sfd.Title = "Guardar";
        sfd.Filter = "Arquivos TXT (*.txt)|*.txt";

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {

                File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, myForm.listBox.Items.OfType<string>());

                //Mensagem de confirmação
                MessageBox.Show("Guardado com sucesso", "Notificação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work, always save the file blank.

Comment: Well, does `myForm.listBox.Items.OfType<string>()` return anything?  If `myForm` is a `Form` then it's not clear what you expect from it because you never actually show that form to the user.  So no interaction was ever made with its controls.  What are you actually trying to get from that form?

Comment: `var myForm = new FormVer();` -- well there is your problem (well, one of them). You create a completely new, completely separate instance of `FormVer` which (assumingly) does *not* have any data in its listbox. You need to make the instance of `FormVer` that *has* the data available here somehow.

Comment: How do I make an instance?
Would I have to create a class?
Sorry I'm new at this I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

```
myForm.listBox.Items.OfType<string>()
```

is going to return an empty enumerable since `Items` contains [ListBoxItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx) instances

The following should work:

```
ListBox listBox = myForm.listBox;
IEnumerable<string> lines = listBox.Items.Select(item => listBox.GetItemText(item));

File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, lines);
```

Comment: I tried your example and gives error in "Select", says it does not contain definition.

Comment: @Amauri Make sur you have `System.Linq` in your usings